# "Cannot access a disposed object." error message shown while trying to open a C# form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, windows-update

[image: Error Message]

This error message pops up for every form I'm trying to open in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. It happened after windows update.

Comment: Are you trying to access a property or method of an object that has been deinstantiated (disposed)?

Comment: Can you share the code if the form?

Comment: @enigmaker No, I was just trying to open the form in design mode from project properties window.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya same error is showing when I try to open the code file.

Comment: It looks this error is from the IDE, and not from your code....is that right?

Comment: If you start a brand new project and add a form to it, do you have the same problem? Or does this only happen with a certain existing project?

Comment: @Alisson Yes. It's from IDE.

Comment: @JohnWu No, a brand new project is working fine. And there was no problem with this project also. It starts after a windows update.

Comment: I am also experiencing this, turns out its a confirmed bug with the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update that occurs if you open a solution from a local OneDrive folder and have "Files on Demand" enabled. Thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/100424/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-2.html

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same problem with Visual Studio 2017 (on Windows 10) with my solutions stored on Microsoft's OneDrive. What I did to fix this was open my local OneDrive settings, find the Files On-Demand setting, and uncheck that checkbox disabling the Files On-Demand feature.
[image]